# Can I record with 50FPS in the camera app to avoid flicker?

Tags: iphone, video, camera

The iPhone camera allows me to choose between 30 and 60 FPS in the settings. However I live in Europe with 50Hz mains frequency. When I am filming old CRTs, I get a bunch of flicker either way. It would be optimal to record at 50 FPS. Is there a way to enforce this? Maybe a 3rd party app? I haven't found  one yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without 3rd party apps: **No**, iOS doesn't allow you to choose the fps.

Yet, there are 3rd party apps that can give you much more control over photo and video settings. [ProCam](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/procam-7/id730712409) for example supports your requested feature.